# From CSV list to XLSX. Numbers recognise as text not as numbers

Tags: excel, python-3.x, csv, xlsxwriter

I am working with CSV datafile.

From this file I took some specific data. These data convey to a list that contains strings of words but also numbers (saved as string, sigh!).
As this:

```
data_of_interest = ["string1", "string2, "242", "765", "string3", ...]
```

I create new XLSX (should have this format) file in which this data have been pasted in.
The script does the work but on the new XLSX file, the numbers (float and int) are pasted in as text.
I could manually convert their format on excel but it would be time consuming.

Is there a way to do it automatically when writing the new XLSX file?

Here the extract of code I used:

```
## import library and create excel file and the working sheet
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("newfile.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet 1')

## take the data from the list (data_of_interest) from csv file
## paste them inside the excel file, in rows and columns
column = 0
row = 0
for value in data_of_interest:
    if type(value) is float:
        sheet.write_number(row, column, value)
    elif type(value) is int:
        sheet.write_number(row, column, value)
    else:
        sheet.write(row, column, value)
    column += 1
row += 1
column = 0
workbook.close()
```

Is the problem related with the fact that the numbers are already `str` type in the original list, so the code cannot recognise that they are `float` or `int` (and so it doesn't write them as numbers)?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try int(value) or float(value) before if block.

All data you read are strings you have to try to convert them into float or int type first.

Example:

```
for value in data_of_interest:
    try:
        value.replace(',', '.') # Note that might change commas to dots in strings which are not numbers
        value = float(value)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    if type(value) is float:
        sheet.write_number(row, column, line)
    else:
        sheet.write(row, column, line)
    column += 1
row += 1
column = 0
workbook.close()
```

Comment: it partially worked!! I have most of the numbers recognised as numbers now. I cannot understand why some of them are not. I found a pattern: numbers with 3 decimals AND decimal numbers starting from 1 (eg: 1,694), are recognised as text. Why? D:

Comment: @Marco by any chance some of them are delimited by comma, and some by dot?

Comment: I checked it since I had the same intuition but actually all of them are delimited by comma. But WAIT! in excel, clicking on one number per time, shows me that some of them are Numbers but some are General

Comment: @Marco float() change type from string to float, when number is delimited by dot. You have to add value.replace(',', '.') before invoking float(). I edited the answer

Comment: No, it's not working. I think the problem is inside the original csv file. There I have some numbers saved as "General" type and some of them as "Number" (the lasts are those with 3 floating numbers after comma). If I manually round them two 2 floating points, they are going to be converted to `float` during writing into the new excel file.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this with XlsxWriter is to use the `strings_to_numbers` [constructor](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#constructor) option:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("newfile.xlsx", {'strings_to_numbers': True})
sheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet 1')

data_of_interest = ["string1", "string2", "242", "765", "string3"]

column = 0
row = 0

for value in data_of_interest:
    sheet.write(row, column, value)
    column += 1

workbook.close()
```

Output: (note that there aren't any warnings about numbers stored as strings):

[image]